# Display a different image within same <img> tag

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to display a different image within the same  tag when a different value is searched in a search bar. Here is the the html code as default when Pikachu is searched. I have provided all of the html as well as javascript that I have used. This is for a freeCodeCamp project called Pokemon Search App. Also when I add this code my "types.innerHTML" for "GHOST" and "POISON" is not displaying.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <title>Pokemon Search App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>Pokemon Search App</h1>
  <input id="search-input" required></input>
  <button id="search-button">Click Me</button>
  <p id="pokemon-name"></p>
  <p id="pokemon-id"></p>
  <p id="weight"></p>
  <p id="height"></p>
  <p id="types"></p>
  <p id="hp"></p>
  <p id="attack"></p>
  <p id="defense"></p>
  <p id="special-attack"></p>
  <p id="special-defense"></p>
  <p id="speed"></p>
  <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/25.png" style="display: none;" id="sprite" class="pikachu-sprite">
  <script src="./script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the javascript I am currently using to change it when 94 (Gengar) is searched.

```
const searchInput = document.getElementById("search-input");
const searchButton = document.getElementById("search-button");
const pokemonName = document.getElementById("pokemon-name");
const pokemonId = document.getElementById("pokemon-id");
const weight = document.getElementById("weight");
const height = document.getElementById("height");
const hp = document.getElementById("hp");
const attack = document.getElementById("attack");
const defense = document.getElementById("defense");
const specialAttack = document.getElementById("special-attack");
const specialDefense = document.getElementById("special-defense");
const speed = document.getElementById("speed");
const types = document.getElementById("types");
const pikachuImage = document.getElementById("sprite");






searchButton.addEventListener('click', function pikachuSearch() {
    if (searchInput.value.toLowerCase() === 'pikachu') {
        pokemonName.innerText = 'PIKACHU';
        pokemonId.innerText = '25';
        weight.innerText = 'Weight: 60';
        height.innerText = 'Height: 4';
        hp.innerText = '35';
        attack.innerText = '55';
        defense.innerText = '40';
        specialAttack.innerText = '50';
        specialDefense.innerText = '50';
        speed.innerText = '90';
        pikachuImage.style.display = "block";
        types.innerHTML = `<span>ELECTRIC</span>`;
    } else if (searchInput.value === '94') {
        pokemonName.innerText = 'GENGAR';
        pokemonId.innerText = '94';
        weight.innerText = '405';
        height.innerText = 'Height: 15';
        hp.innerText = '60';
        attack.innerText = '65';
        defense.innerText = '60';
        specialAttack.innerText = '130';
        specialDefense.innerText = '75';
        speed.innerText = '110';
        gengarImage.style.display = "block";
        types.innerHTML = `
        <span>GHOST</span>
        <span>POISON</span>`;
        changeImgSrc();
    } else if (searchInput.innerText = 'Red') {
        // Display an alert if the input is empty
        alert('Pokémon not found');
    }
});




function changeImageSrc() {
  pikachuImage.src = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/94.png';
}
```

```
function changeImageSrc() {
  pikachuImage.src = '<https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/94.png>';
}
```

Comment: what console errors do you have

Comment: pikachuImage.src = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/94.png';
remove the '<' and '>' in the src

Comment: `pikachuImage.src = '<https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/...` <--  you have a leading `<` which should not be there.

Comment: BTW,  `githubusercontent.com` is not intended for use as an image-host or content-host for other applications - don't be surprised if your images don't load (even after you fix the syntax error in your code) because GitHub might block hot-linked images.

Comment: That still throws an error. I am doing this through freeCodeCamp so it doesn't say what is causing the error. Also after I change it the "GHOST" and "POISON" aren't displaying from the template literal.

Answer (score 0):

Updated: I ran through each step on the FreeCodeCamp project:

Here is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <title>Pokemon PokeDex</title>
        <style>
            .container {
                width: 25%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container mt-4">
            <div id="search">
                <input
                    type="text"
                    id="search-input"
                    class="form-control"
                    required />
            </div>
            <div
                id="error"
                class="alert alert-danger mb-3 mt-3"
                style="display: none">
                <strong>Error:</strong>
                Pokemon not found.
            </div>
            <div id="content" style="display: none">
                <div id="pokemon-image">
                    <span>
                        <img src="" id="sprite" />
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-floating mb-3 mt-3">
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        class="form-control"
                        id="pokemon-name"
                        size="30"
                        readonly
                        disabled />
                    <label for="pokemon-name">Name:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-floating mb-3 mt-3">
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        class="form-control"
                        id="pokemon-id"
                        size="30"
                        readonly
                        disabled />
                    <label for="pokemon-id">ID:</label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-floating mb-3 mt-3">
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        class="form-control"
                        id="weight"
                        size="30"
                        readonly
                        disabled />
                    <label for="weight">Weight:</label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-floating mb-3 mt-3">
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        class="form-control"
                        id="height"
                        size="30"
                        readonly
                        disabled />
                    <label for="height">Height:</label>
                </div>

                <div id="types"></div>

                <div class="form-floating mb-3 mt-3">
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        class="form-control"
                        id="hp"
                        size="30"
                        readonly
                        disabled />
                    <label for="hp">HP:</label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-floating mb-3 mt-3">
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        class="form-control"
                        id="attack"
                        size="30"
                        readonly
                        disabled />
                    <label for="attack">Attack:</label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-floating mb-3 mt-3">
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        class="form-control"
                        id="defense"
                        size="30"
                        readonly
                        disabled />
                    <label for="defense">Defense:</label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-floating mb-3 mt-3">
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        class="form-control"
                        id="special-attack"
                        size="30"
                        readonly
                        disabled />
                    <label for="special-attack">Special Attack:</label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-floating mb-3 mt-3">
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        class="form-control"
                        id="special-defense"
                        size="30"
                        readonly
                        disabled />
                    <label for="special-defense">Special Defense:</label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-floating mb-3 mt-3">
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        class="form-control"
                        id="speed"
                        size="30"
                        readonly
                        disabled />
                    <label for="speed">Speed:</label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div>
                <button
                    type="button"
                    id="search-button"
                    class="btn btn-primary mt-2"
                    onclick="pokemon_search">
                    Search
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="js/script.js" defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the JS

```
const element = document.getElementById("search-button");
element.addEventListener("click", pokemon_search);

let uri =
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/";

function pokemon_search() {
    let query = document
        .getElementById("search-input")
        .value.toLowerCase();

    const parent = document.getElementById("types");
    parent.innerHTML = "";

    if (query == "pikachu" || query == 25) {
        // PIKACHU, #25 or 25, Weight: 60 or 60, Height: 4 or 4, 35, 55, 40, 50, 50, and 90,
        document.getElementById("error").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("content").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("pokemon-name").value = "PIKACHU";
        document.getElementById("pokemon-id").value = 25;
        document.getElementById("weight").value = 60;
        document.getElementById("height").value = 4;
        document.getElementById("hp").value = 55;
        document.getElementById("attack").value = 40;
        document.getElementById("defense").value = 50;
        document.getElementById("special-attack").value = 50;
        document.getElementById("special-defense").value = 50;
        document.getElementById("speed").value = 90;

        let id = document.getElementById("pokemon-id").value;
        sprite.src = uri + id + ".png";

        type_setter(1)

    } else if (query == "gengar" || query == 94) {
        // GENGAR, #94 or 94, Weight: 405 or 405, Height: 15 or 15, 60, 65, 60, 130, 75, and 110,

        document.getElementById("error").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("content").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("pokemon-name").value = "GENGAR";
        document.getElementById("pokemon-id").value = 94;
        document.getElementById("weight").value = 405;
        document.getElementById("height").value = 15;
        document.getElementById("types").value = "Electric";
        document.getElementById("hp").value = 60;
        document.getElementById("attack").value = 65;
        document.getElementById("defense").value = 60;
        document.getElementById("special-attack").value = 130;
        document.getElementById("special-defense").value = 75;
        document.getElementById("speed").value = 110;

        let id = document.getElementById("pokemon-id").value;
        sprite.src = uri + id + ".png";

        type_setter(2)
        type_setter(3)

    } else {
        document.getElementById("content").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("error").style.display = "block";
    }
}

function type_setter(id) {

    const pokemon_types = {
        1: "Electric",
        2: "Ghost",
        3: "Posion",
    };

    parent = document.getElementById('types');

    for (const [num, pokemon_type] of Object.entries(
        pokemon_types
    )) {
        if (num == id) {
            const div = document.createElement('div');
            div.className = "form-floating mb-3 mt-3"
            const type = document.createElement('input');
            type.className = "form-control";
            type.value = pokemon_type;
            type.disabled = true;
            type.readOnly = true
            var label = document.createElement('label');
            label.innerHTML = 'Type:';
            label.for = 'inputText';
            div.appendChild(type);
            div.appendChild(label);
            parent.appendChild(div);
        }
    }
}
```

The type setter should be redone so that you don't have to call it multiple times for multiple types like in the Gengar section, but that can be fixed later.

Comment: Please explain how this solves the question at hand

Comment: I don't think this works.

Comment: I`m sorry. I think I misread the problem. I will look again.